# How to switch base layer based on internet connection availability

Tags: openlayers, javascript, google-maps

My application ( html+ JavaScript) use Google map as a base layer. I also setup OSM as an offline base layer to use when there is no internet connection.

Now I'm locking for a way to make app check for internet connection, if there is, then use Google map as a base layer. if not, then use OSM.

Comment: this is more of a stackoverflow question than a GIS one

Comment: Are you having trouble with the connection test or the layer switching?

Answer (score 3):

You can listen for 'loaderror' event, that will be thrown, when loading of Google Map tile fails. Here is example with regular WMS layer (full example in http://jsfiddle.net/D3Eha/2/)

```
var wmsLayer, workingOffline = false;

wmsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenLayers WMS",
    "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?",
    {layers: 'basic'},
    {
        attribution: 'Provided by OSGeo',
        tileOptions: {
            eventListeners: {
                'loaderror': function(evt) {
                    if (workingOffline == false) {
                        console.log('Tile load error, switching to offline map');
                        workingOffline = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }        
    }
);
```

It's trickier to detect, when computer is online again. For example, when you go offline, start periodical timer to load some image from Internet. If it succeeds, you are back online.

Answer (score 0):

I devised that solution, you need to adapt it to your case.

```
    var backupLayerUrl = {
        url: "http://b.tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/",
        type: "png"
    }

tileOptions = {
            eventListeners: {
                'loaderror': function(e) {
                    console.dir(e);
                    var newUrl = backupLayerUrl.url;
                    var oldUrl = e.object.url;
                    var oUS = oldUrl.split("/");//oldUrlSplitted

                    var type = backupLayerUrl.type;

                    var z = oUS[oUS.length-3];
                    var x = oUS[oUS.length-2];
                    var y = oUS[oUS.length-1].split(".")[0];

                    var layerType = e.object.layer.CLASS_NAME.split(".")[e.object.layer.CLASS_NAME.split(".").length-1];

                    if (layerType != "OSM"){
                        var ymax = 1 << z;
                        y = ymax - y - 1;
                    }

                    newUrl += z + "/" + x + "/" + y + "." + type;
                    e.object.imgDiv.src = newUrl;
                }
            }
        };

    var mylayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS("Layer Name", "/layer_url/",
              {     tileOptions: tileOptions,
                    projection: epsg900913,
                    alpha: true,
                    type: 'png',
                    visibility: false,
                    isBaseLayer: true,
                    getURL: getTileURL
              });
```