# Is there a way to know if an error occurred while loading a WMS layer, in OpenLayers 2?

Tags: javascript, events, openlayers, layer, wms

I am working with OpenLayers 2. I am using the events "loadstart" and "loadend" from [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.events).

When I use OpenLayers.Layers.WMS, i want to have some kind of callback when there is a loading error. For example, when I enter an incorrect SLD filter, I want to have some feedback about the layer not being loaded correctly. Unfortunately, "loadend" doesn't provide this kind of error detection.

I already found [this question](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail//openlayers-users/2012-January/023772.html) where someone else has the same problem.

Is there even an event that signals this kind of error? Is there something like a "layerfail" or "layererror" event?

How could I implement this?

Thank you.

João

Comment: I don't believe it is possible. You can get the aborted property that is sent to the tileloaded callback, but not the reason for the failure. There is an answer here about requesting information from the  header of the request that you might be able to do something with: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28741/openlayers-wms-loaderror-event-get-response-text-of

Comment: Hi, @JohnBarça. I don't really need the failing reason. I gave the filter example just to illustrate the problem. I just want an event that indicates there has been an error. I already tried "loadwarning", "loadfail", "loaderror", but none of them seem to be defined in the version of OpenLayers i'm using. :s How could I solve this? You said something anout some "aborted property". Could explain this better, please? Thanks.

Comment: Here is one of my old answer regarding loaderror event, which seemed to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604483/how-to-switch-base-layer-based-on-internet-connection-availability/15612155#15612155